# How do you set the time in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

How do you set the time in Postgres?  I've set the time zone in Postgres to Eastern Standard Time using `set timezone='-5'`.  However, the time was 45 minutes off where it should have been.  Thinking Postgres was getting the time from Linux, I set the date in Linux using `date -s="24 AUG 2011 13:48"` and rebooted, and yet the problem persists.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Postgresql will get its time (not necessarily time zone) setting from the OS, yes.

If your Linux machine has internet access, you can install NTP to keep the time in sync. Simply setting the time locally *should* be persisted back to the BIOS RTC, though.

Comment: Thank you!  Super helpful response.  I was remotely accessing a server and setting the time locally and wondering why the remote time wasn't being set.  Foolish on my part.  I have installed NTP, and things are working swimmingly.  Thanks again.